# QDockWidget Content bug with titlebar

Tags: qt, position, qdockwidget

Here is my problem: I created a QDockWidget and put a QGraphicsView in it, while it is floating everything shows up correctly, but if Dock it somewhere, the starting X and Y of my content is on the titlebar of the QDockWidget. Obviously, it should be under:

```
tilesetWindow = new QDockWidget(tr("Tileset"), this);
tilesetWindow->setMinimumSize(256,256);
tilesetWindow->setFloating(true);
connect(tilesetWindow, SIGNAL(visibilityChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(triggeredTileset()));

tilesetViewer = new QGraphicsView(tilesetWindow);
tilesetViewer->resize(256,256);
tilesetViewer->show();
```

An image to illustrate this: http://img86.xooimage.com/files/d/7/6/problem-391a96a.png

I've tried to put the QGraphicsView in a container and then in the QDockWidget but had the same result as above. it's the only place where I write code for the QDockWidget.

How can I make it start at the right place when it is Docked?

Edit:

I tried in a new QtProject and made a QDockWidget with a QTextBrowser in it and had the same bug:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget(this, 0);
    dock->setFloating(true);

    QTextBrowser *t = new QTextBrowser(dock);
    t->show();
}
```

I'm missing something I think...

Qt Creator 2.4.1 
Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)

Comment: This kind of problem tends to occur when a widget isn't parented properly. Is `tilesetWindow` an immediate child of the `QMainWindow`?

Comment: `this` in the code, is the `QMainWindow`, so yes. I tried: 
`this->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, tilesetWindow, Qt::Horizontal);`
But had the same result.

Comment: Hmm. I can't help you further then, but if you give your Qt version, it might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the QDockWidget as the Parent, you also need to set the QDockWidget's Widget as the QGraphicsView, or any other you want.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget(this, 0);
dock->setFloating(true);

QTextBrowser *t = new QTextBrowser(dock);
dock->setWidget(t);
}
```